# Why for..in loop is not traversing through an object's prototype

Tags: javascript, object

I was reading through MDN's [working with objects guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Enumerating_all_properties_of_an_object) and realized that I can't make this statement happen in practice:

> for...in loops: This method traverses all enumerable properties of an object and its prototype chain

Here's the code that I've written for testing this:

```js
var obj1 = {
 'one':1,
 'two':2,
 'three':3
}

var obj2 = Object.create(obj1);
 obj2.test = 'test';
// Let's see what's inside obj2 now
console.info(obj2);
// Yep! the __proto__ is set to obj1

// This lists the object properties and
// returns them as a string, nothing special!
function showProps(obj, objName) {
  var result = "";
  for (var i in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        result += objName + "." + i + " = " + obj[i] + "\n";
    }
  }
  return result;
}

// According to MDN the for..in loop traverses all
// enumerable properties of an object and its prototype chain
// https://goo.gl/QZyDas
console.info( showProps(obj2, 'obj2') );

// But in the console you can see that showProps returns
// only the obj2.test property for obj2, meaning that it
// hasn't traveresed through it's prototype chain, do you know why?!
```

Comment: This is exactly the problem when people get into cargo-culting `if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i))`

Comment: @Bergi Thank you for the valuable input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have a check for `obj.hasOwnProperty(i)`. If you remove that, it should traverse the prototype as well.

Comment: oh! that was a dumb mistake of mine. thanks!